# map function parameters onto nested list in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I think there is a way to do this - I just can't find the exact syntax.

I want to map a function that takes three parameters on a list of tuples of size three. Something like:

```
(def mylist '((1 2 3)(3 4 5)))

(defn myfunc [a b c] (println "this is the first value in this tuple: " a))

(map myfunc mylist)
```

Can someone give me the precise syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**d11wtq**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20469860/1202461) is a very good one, and it's the right way to go, unless you already have a function you want to map.

So, if `myfunc` is external function, it's better to use `apply` rather than write additional wrapper:

```
(map (partial apply myfunc) mylist)
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need a pair of square braces in there to destructure the nested list elements.

```
(defn myfunc
  [[a b c]]
  (println "this is the first value in this tuple: " a))
```

Be aware, however, that because `map` returns a lazy-seq, you may not get the side-effects you're after here, unless you force evaluation of the seq with `doall`, or inspect the seq in the REPL.

Documentation: [http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special Forms--Binding Forms (Destructuring)](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29)